# Authorization scope issues despite passing "scope" parameter

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I am experiencing issues requesting "upload" authorization from Vimeo users OTHER than the user that created/registered the app.

**Example:**
User-A creates/register's new App-A via the Vimeo developer console.  User-B is asked to authorize App-A to upload on their behalf.  User-B is redirected to Vimeo authorization UI and sees the following:

**This app will enable you to:**
Access all of your videos
**This app will not allow you to:**
Like videos
Update your video info
Upload videos to your account
Delete your videos

Despite specifying scope in the authentication request URL:

https://vimeo.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&locale=en_US&oauth_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxx.com%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Fvimeo%2Fverify&response_type=code&scope=upload&state={%22sessionId%22%3A%2243a9a9d1a7bd44d5a27d0f91b6185875%22}

**BUT...**

If I send the same request, but login as User-A instead then:

**This app will enable you to:**
Access all of your videos
Upload videos to your account
**This app will not allow you to:**
Like videos
Update your video info
Delete your videos

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Check the upload permissions you have been granted. If you only have owner permission, you can only request upload scope for the app owner.

If you have additional permissions, they are based on the target users subscription level.

If you think you should still be able to upload, or if you need additional upload permissions you will need to contact vimeo directly at vimeo.com/help/contact